# Saving jpeg - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process?

Tags: c#, image, crop, system.drawing

I'm trying to crop a jpeg file using the (x,y) coordinates,width and height and save the output in the same location(i.e replace). I tried the below code but its not working.

```
public void CropImage(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{

string image_path = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.jpg";

var img = Image.FromFile(image_path);

Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(crop.Width, crop.Height);
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    gr.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), crop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}


if (System.IO.File.Exists(image_path))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(image_path);
}

bmp.Save(image_path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

**This gives an error like:**

> An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.jpg' because it is being used by another
>   process.

When I add `img.Dispose()` I don't get the above error and I'm able to save it.But it saves the blank image with the given width and height.

Can anyone help me out with this??

Comment: The old image is still blocked by your code. You can pick another name or read one of many post how to unblock.. Search for 'c# Save jpeg IOException'

Comment: @TaW, Even when I give a new path, I was getting a blank image with the given width and height

Comment: It shouldn't be empty, unless you dispose of it. Watch the order of the Rectangles though! See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @TaW I tried `using` so that save IOEcxeption won't come, its still not working.. Order of Rectangle is proper

Answer (score 8):

```
public void CropImage(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    string imagePath = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.jpg";
    Bitmap croppedImage;

    // Here we capture the resource - image file.
    using (var originalImage = new Bitmap(imagePath))
    {
        Rectangle crop = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        // Here we capture another resource.
        croppedImage = originalImage.Clone(crop, originalImage.PixelFormat);

    } // Here we release the original resource - bitmap in memory and file on disk.

    // At this point the file on disk already free - you can record to the same path.
    croppedImage.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // It is desirable release this resource too.
    croppedImage.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This also saves a blank jpeg file with given height and width. I had given full path in imagepath like ` @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.jpg`

Comment: I don't know why, its giving me a blank jpeg file

Comment: @J19 - Perhaps the area to be cropped gets on the white part of the image?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.. Thanx a lot.. Simple mistake,but I was finding it difficult to make out.

Comment: The image quality of the cropped image is very poor.. Is there any way to crop the image without losing its quality?

Comment: @J19 - Don't use Jpeg.